# How to execute a function when a button is clicked?

Tags: javascript

What is the best practice for making a function execute when a button is clicked in JavaScript without using jQuery?

I'm looking for a solution that looks like this:

```
var button = document.getElementById('myButton');

function sayHello() {
    alert('hello');
}

button.attachFunctionToClick(sayHello);
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.onclick

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM_Client_Object_Cross-Reference/DOM_Events

Comment: `AddEventListener` for standards-compliant browsers, `attachEvent` for IE<=8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standards way of attaching events is like this:

```
var button = document.getElementById("myButton");
button.addEventListener("click", sayHello, false);
```

[Read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/EventTarget.addEventListener)

Older versions of ie (less than 9) don't support addeventlistener though and you'll have to fall back to the attachEvent function.

```
button.attachEvent('click',sayHello);
```

Of course you can still just add to the `onclick` method of the element like this:

```
button.onclick = sayHello
```

The above 3 examples assume you're not passing any parameters to the callback functions, which means that the only arguments they will receive will be the event object.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the IE9- `attachEvent`. Very informative answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
var button = document.getElementById('myButton');
function sayHello() {
    alert('hello');
}

if(document.addEventListener)
    button.addEventListener('click',sayHello,false);
else
    button.attachEvent('click',sayHello);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    function test() {
        alert('aaa');
    }
</script>

<input type="button" onclick="test()" />
```

or

```
<input type="button" id="myButton" />
```

This goes at the end of the page before the close body tag:

```
<script>
    function test() {
        alert('aaa');
    }
    var button = document.getElementById('myButton');
    button.onclick = test;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For browser compliance, here's a simple helper function:

```
function setEvent (element, event, handler) {
  if(document.addEventListener){
    element.addEventListener(event, handler);
   }else{
      element.attachEvent("on" + event, handler, false);
   }
};
```

**IMPORTANT**: Notice the `"on" + event` here. It's used for events in IE. See more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa741902%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

[**EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/PGdsb/)

or you may try:

```
button.onclick = sayHello;
```

> Because it was essentially part of DOM 0, this method is very widely
>   supported and requires no special cross–browser code; hence it is
>   normally used to register event listeners dynamically unless the extra
>   features of addEventListener() are needed.

[**EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/z5ffR/)

[attachEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536343%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - Used for IE < 9:

> Binds the specified function to an event, so that the function gets
>   called whenever the event fires on the object.

[addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/EventTarget.addEventListener):

> addEventListener() registers a single event listener on a single
>   target. The event target may be a single element in a document, the
>   document itself, a window, or an XMLHttpRequest.
>
> To register more than one event listener for the target, call
>   addEventListener() for the same target but with different event types,
>   event listeners or capture parameters.